# Converting "unsigned char *" to "char *" (and string)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a pet project with the libsodium library, and found that converting unsigned char * to char * was less straight forward than I imagined. Also I first was confused because the tests were passing in Release mode and only bit later I realised they were not passing in Debug mode.
So I came up with the following:

```
std::string string_from_uchar(const unsigned char * c, unsigned long long lc)
    {
        unsigned char * cc = new unsigned char[lc+1] ;
        std::strncpy((char *) cc, (char *) c, lc);
        cc[lc] = 0;
        char* cr = reinterpret_cast<char *> (cc);
        std::string ret(cr);
        delete[](cr);
        return ret;
    }
```

While it now passed the tests, I was be grateful if someone could check if it is the right way of doing it (for instance would that work on another environment like gcc or clang?).

Comment: Don't mix `new` and `free()`.

Comment: Good chances are that your tests were failing for some entirely different reason, and that the fix that you have implemented is a work-around that masks the underlying issue, rather than fixing it.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ: Good catch !

Comment: Don't use `new` or `free()`.

Comment: @callmeSteve I should have added that mixing these gives you undefined behavior, which could well explain the weird behavior of your test code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : Could be, it was a malloc (instead of a new) first and there was no problem either that's why I thought it wasn't relevant. but I agree since it was an undefined it could be that part as well. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're massively over-thinking this.

The copy is redundant, as is the extra dynamic allocation and the addition of a null terminator (because `std::string` has a constructor that accepts a length argument for just this sort of occasion).

The various `char` can be aliased, so simply:

```
std::string string_from_uchar(const unsigned char * c, unsigned long long lc)
{
    return std::string((const char*)c, lc);
}
```

In fact, if you use the constructor that takes a range, you don't even need the cast:

```
std::string string_from_uchar(const unsigned char * c, unsigned long long lc)
{
    return std::string(c, c + lc);
}
```

It barely even warrants being in its own function.

Comment: I believe you can do just `std::string( c, c + lc )` without any cast. Correct me if I'm wrong. It's been a long time since used that beast. :)

Comment: Thanks for that example! You just forgot the `c +` ;-). Here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14f4c576def38129

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Excellent!

Comment: Thanks for the propositions, it looks more what I was hoping the conversion would be and they give the right results too. However now my test is crashing.

Comment: @callmeSteve: Due to something else. None of us has any idea what this "test" is or in what way it's "crashing" so we can't help.

Comment: Ok got it! it was indeed unrelated (out of the scope of the function), not sure how the function was masking it but I will let it go.

Comment: @callmeSteve: That's what happens when you cause undefined behaviour: literally anything. A rational explanation can be reached (with sufficient information and examination) but there's really no point.